# Cauchy Residue Theorem Question

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I am finding difficulty with the following couple of problems

a) show that $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(\pi x)}{2x-1}
 \ne\frac{\pi}{2}$$

I've been trying to do this over a semi-circle, but keep getting the answer -pi instead of -pi/2. It is correct that the arc integrates to 0 right?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Is that *really* the correct integrand?

Comment: should be (2x-1) integrand. Fixed now

Comment: Ok then, what function are you integrating, and over which curve? You probably need an indentation around $x=\frac12$ (which will only pick up half the residue in the limit).

Comment: Singularity at x = 1/2, simple pole there. So by residue thm, the integral is 2*pi*i lim z->1/2 of (z-1/2)f(z) which is pi*i*e^i*pi/2 if im not mistaken

Comment: You still haven't said which function $f(z)$ you are integrating, or which curve you are integrating over (all needed for using the residue theorem). If you don't provide those, we can only guess where your error is.

Comment: f(z) = (e^ipiz)/ 2z-1. Integrating over semi-circle from -R to R in upper plane. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Well, then as I said already a number of comments ago, the integral along the indentation around $x=\frac12$ will only pick up half the residue at $\frac12$. See for example http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319959

Comment: Why do I need an indentation here?

Comment: $$\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_{-a}^{a}\frac{\cos(\pi x)}{2x-1}\space\text{d}x=\lim_{a\to\infty}\left[\frac{1}{2}\text{Si}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\pi x\right)\right]_{-a}^{a}=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{a\to\infty}\left[\text{Si}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\pi x\right)\right]_{-a}^{a}=-\frac{\pi}{2}$$