# How to deal with poles along contour of integration

Tags: complex-analysis, intuition, contour-integration, cauchy-principal-value

Suppose one has an integral of a real (or complex) function that has at least one pole that lies on the contour of integration, for example: $$\int_{-a}^{a}\frac{f(x)}{x}dx$$ Clearly such an integral is undefined in the normal sense.

My question is, how does one deal with such integrals in general? I've heard of the notion of a *Cauchy Principal value*, but not sure I fully understand the method. Does one deform the contour slightly to avoid the pole(s) and then take the limit as this deformation tends to zero, i.e. $$\mathcal{P}\int_{-a}^{a}\frac{f(x)}{x}dx=\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0}\left(\int_{-a}^{-\delta}\frac{f(x)}{x}dx+\int_{\delta}^{a}\frac{f(x)}{x}dx\right)\;\text{?}$$

I'm approaching this from a physicist's perspective, in particular in relation to the Feynman propagator, which as an integral along the real axis is not well-defined since the integrand has two poles lying on the real axis. In the standard approach the contour is deformed such that it does not pass through the poles, and then the residue theorem is applied. However, the issue of whether this converges to the actual integral once the limit is taken is usually glossed over. In a more technical approach, is one technically taking the Cauchy principal value of the original integral?

Comment: In your example: $P \int_{-a}^a f(x)/x\equiv\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}\int_{-a}^{\epsilon} f(x)/x+\int_{\epsilon}^a f(x)/x$. This definition induces some nice properties for example, if $f(x)$ even the Principal value vanishs

Comment: From a complex analyis perspective, your considerations are more or less correct :
$$
P \int_{-a}^a f(x)/x=-\pi i f(0)-\int_{closure}f(z)dz$$. Here i assumed that $f(x)$ is analytic in the upper half plane and $closure$ is some path that closes the contour of integration so that we can apply residue theorem

Comment: @tired         In terms of the Feynman propagator, is one technically taking the Cauchy principal value of the associated contour integral?

Comment: @op more or less, you have to include additionally the contributions from the small indents around the poles of your propagator in k-space. If my brain serves well, there are two of them in the case of Feynman's Propagator for a free (or nicely renormalized) quantum field which might cancel due to symmetries of the underlying physical system

Comment: In a Feynman propagator, you never take the Cauchy principle value blindly. Instead, you move the contour around the pole. The small shift of the contour in the imaginary direction corresponds to regularizing the integral in a certain manner. Remember, everything in physics is approximation. The regularization you employ should reflect the difference between the real world and the ideal equation you write down to model the system. This usually dictates which direction you should move the contour.

Comment: @achillehui    Isn't the Cauchy principal value simply a method of regularising an otherwise ill-defined integral though? In the Feynman propagator case is one simply deform the contour then taking the limit as these shifts around the poles tend to zero and then equating this to the propagator, i.e. essentially defining the propagator in terms of a choice of regulating the poles?

Comment: Taking Cauchy PV is not a reasonable choice for physics. It is an arbitrary choice of getting a number from an ill-defined integral by mathematicians. The $\epsilon$ term in a regularized Feynman propagator (in momentum representation) typically comes from a exponential decay in spatial or temporal domain. It reflect our belief effects are localized and there is no action at a distance. The "model" we use to model the real world is an approximation, if the integral is singular because of the approximation, we should regularize it in a way compatible to the approximation.

Comment: @achillehui    So is the point that we make the physical assumption that the propagator should be a finite quantity and so we regularise its integral representation to ensure a finite result?

Comment: @user35305, Yes. it is a fundamental belief that the physical world is describable.  the true "propagator" should be finite or the approximation we make fail to model the real world correctly.

Comment: @achillehui    Ah ok. So is this the assumption that one usual makes when regulating the integral to get a finite result?

Comment: @user35305 to be honest, quite a few physicists didn't make any assumption and just follow the recipe. This is okay because the ultimate gauge whether something is correct or not is not the correctness of math (this is partly because the model we use can be wrong), but whether the result matches experiment.

Comment: if it's a simple pole, you can use the half residue theorem (which is what tired was talking about); you can find a thread about it here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319959/how-to-rigorously-justify-picking-up-half-a-residue