# Inconsistency of DCT and Residue theorem

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, residue-calculus

Consider the integral limit
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{n\sin(x/n)}{x(1+x^2)}dx$$

By dominated convergence theorem, the integral equals 
$$\int^\infty_{-\infty} \frac1{1+x^2}dx=\pi$$

If we use residue theorem to evaluate the integral, by taking a infinitely large semi-circle on the upper half plane(small indent at origin), the arc integral vanishes, then we get
$$\int^\infty_{-\infty} \frac{n\sin(x/n)}{x(1+x^2)}dx=2\pi iRes_i=n\pi \sinh (\pi /n)$$
Then taking the limit on $n$, the integral equals $\pi^2$.

What mistake did I make?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MarcoCantarini Can you please show how?

Comment: @MarcoCantarini Oh sorry I found my mistake. I think this question should be deleted. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: There's a more fundamental error here - the integral should evaluate to $n \pi (1 - e^{-1/n})$, which has the correct limit.

Comment: @B.Mehta Would you mind showing how your derived this expression?

Comment: Sure, I'll write an answer now.

Comment: You simply did something wrong. One possibility is you assumed that $\sin$ is bounded in the upper half-plane;  it's  not. That messes up residue-theorem calculations; you can't show the integral over the circular part of the contour tends to $0$. The standard fix is to note that $\sin(t)$ is the imaginary part of $e^{it}$ (for real $t$); the function $e^{iz}$ _is_ bounded in the upper half plane.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Although that’s maybe not what really caused my mistake, that’s what I didn’t realize before. Thanks.

Comment: Really? What reason _did_ you have for saying "the arc integral vanishes"?

Comment: @Szeto I've posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is that you assumed the large arc integral vanishes as $R \to \infty$, which is unfortunately not true for $\frac{\sin z}{z(1+z^2)}$, as it is unbounded there. Instead, observe that $\sin z$ is the imaginary part of $e^{iz}$, which is bounded for the relevant region. Specifically, if $z = x + iy$ and $y > 0$, then $|e^{iz}|=e^{-y}<1$. So, instead calculate
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{ne^{i\frac zn}}{z(1+z^2)}\,dz=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(z)\,dz$$
and take its imaginary part.
However, switching to this gives a (simple) pole at the origin, which needs to be dealt with. So, we take a small dent at the origin instead.

Use the contour $\gamma$ consisting of the four paths:

- $[\epsilon, R]$,
- a semicircle $|z| = R$ and $\operatorname{Im} z > 0$ (counterclockwise) - call this $C_R$,
- $[-R, -\epsilon]$
- a semicircle $|z| = \epsilon$ and $\operatorname{Im} z > 0$ (clockwise) - call this $C_\epsilon$.

Inside the contour, there is a simple pole at $i$ with residue
$$\operatorname{Res}(f,i)= -\frac{ne^{-\frac 1n}}{2}$$
so we have
$$\int_\gamma f(z) \, dz = -i\pi n e^{-\frac1n}.$$

On the outer semicircle, we have $f(z) < \frac{1}{z(1+z^2)}$, which is $\mathcal{O}(R^{-3})$. So, $\int_{C_R} f(z)\,dz$ is $\mathcal{O}(R^{-2})$, hence vanishes in the limit.

For the inner semicircle, observe that $f(z)$ has a simple pole at the origin so we 'pick up half the residue', as we are going around halfway. (For details of how this really works, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319959/how-to-rigorously-justify-picking-up-half-a-residue?rq=1).) Further, remember that this is traversed clockwise so we actually pick up $-\frac{1}{2}$ of the residue. $\operatorname{Res}(f,0) = n$, so
$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{C_\epsilon} f(z)\,dz=-\frac{1}{2}\cdot 2\pi i \cdot n=-i\pi n.$$

Combining, we get
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(z)\,dz = n \pi i - n \pi i e^{-\frac{1}{n}}=i n \pi (1 - e^{-\frac{1}{n}})$$
and taking the imaginary part gives
$$\int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{n\sin(x/n)}{x(1+x^2)}dx=n\pi(1-e^{-\frac{1}{n}}).$$

Finally, notice that $\lim_{n \to \infty} n \pi (1 - e^{-\frac{1}{n}}) = \pi$, as expected.